# What code do I need to calculate a checksum for any barcode, and to verify/validate existing checksums?

Tags: c#, barcode, barcode-scanner, checksum

There are many barcode types, and sizes (lengths). Is there a common set of algorithms I can use to calculate a checksum for any barcode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a very common checksum calculator algorithm.  Various barcodes (and other digit entry schemes) use them to validate the scanner (or the human) entered all the digits properly.  One of the first examples, and the most commonly understood checksum algorithm is the Luhn algorithm, which is known for its use on credit cards; but many variations on it exist.  At their core, though, most use the same algorithm.

The common algorithm uses an array of weights corresponding to the positions of the digits, a modulo divisor, and a flag indicating either a "product add" or "product digit add" scheme.

### Pseudocode

```
int:computeChecksum(string:inputData, int[len(inputData)]: weightArray, int:divisor, Boolean:productDigitAdd)
{

    If the number of digits in inputData is not equal to the number of elements in weightArray
        raise an invalidWeightArray exception
    endif

    create an int:checksum and set it to zero

    For int:position = each digit in inputData
        int:digitProduct = value of inputData digit at [position] times the weightArray at [position] 
        If productDigitAdd then
            for int:prodPosition = each digit in digitProduct
                checksum = checksum + digitProduct[prodPosition]
            end for
        else
            checksum = checksum + digitProduct
        end if
    end for

    int:remainder = checksum modulo divided by divisor
    return remainder
}
```

### Common Schemes

Check digit schemes are in common use throughout various industries, and barcode production and verification is just one.  Here is a list of some of the common check digit schemes that can be used with this algorithm:

- UPC-A barcode: the weights are twelve digits of {3,1,3,1,3,1,3,1,3,1,3,1}, the divisor is 10, and the productDigitAdd value is false.
- EAN-13 barcode: the weights are {1,3,1,3,1,3,1,3,1,3,1,3,1}, the divisor is 10, and the productDigitAdd value is false.
- Code 128 barcode: the digits are the value of the code of the bars, not the values the barcode contains (e.g. the barcode symbol value of 65 represents the ASCII letter 'A' in modes A and B, but is the pair of digits '33' in mode C); the weights are {1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ... through the total number of barcode symbols, 1}, where 1 is the check digit weight at the right end; the divisor is 103; and the productDigitAdd value is false.
- POSTNET barcode: the weights are {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}, the divisor is 10, and the productDigitAdd value is false.
- 16-digit credit cards: the weights are an array of sixteen digits, {2,1,2,1 ... 2,1}, the divisor is 10, and the productDigitAdd value is true.  This is the Luhn algorithm.
- ISBN (book numbers): the weights are {10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1}, the divisor is 11, and the productDigitAdd field is false.
- Routing Transit Number (on bank checks): the weights are {3,7,1,3,7,1,3,7,1}, the divisor is 10, and the productDigitAdd field is false.

### Validation

To validate a barcode with this algorithm, simply compare its output to zero.  Non-zero values indicate failure.

A common mistake is to try to isolate the check digit, then compare the output of the routine to the check digit that was isolated.  It's much simpler and safer to simply include the check digit in the overall loop and then compare the output to zero.  This algorithm then continues to work for check digits that are embedded in positions other than the right end of the barcode, or where the check digit has a non-one weight.

### Generation

You can also use the same algorithm to compute a check digit, as you would when generating a new barcode.  In your input data, one of the digits will be reserved for the position of the check digit.  This is commonly, but not always, the rightmost digit.  Set that position of the input digit array to zero.  Call the algorithm as you would to verify the inputData, then subtract the output of the algorithm from the modulo divisor. Replace the zero placeholder in the input digit array with the subtracted output.

### Special cases

The Luhn algorithm is often implemented very informally.  A common way to describe it is "double every other digit, then add the digits of the sums, and the last digit must be the check digit."  This simplistically works for 16 digit cards, but can lead to inflexible code which is often implemented using case statements to handle different length card numbers, etc.

ISBN numbers (and others) use a divisor of 11, but this can yield a "10" as an output check digit. A two digit value doesn't fit in the barcode position reserved for one digit.  The ISBN specification says that a "10 shall be replaced by the letter 'X'".  Other schemes I've encountered simply discard as impossible any numbers that yield two-digit check digit results.

For schemes like this or others that use non-numeric values, such as [Vehicle Identification Numbers (VINs)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_identification_number#Check-digit_calculation) on cars sold in the USA and Canada, a solid approach is to change this routine from accepting a "string" as the input data and instead converting it into accepting an array of input values.  Then perform a translation step on the array before and after this routine to map the given symbols to the necessary values.  Normally I keep one version of this routine specialized to accept a string type for input, as most programs deal with barcodes as strings.

I have encountered older check digit schemes that include negative values in the weight array.  They get subtracted from the sum instead of added, but otherwise everything works the same way.

A very common optimization, especially in embedded devices such as barcode scanners, is to accept a weight array shorter than the number of digits, and extend it to the left by as many places as there are digits in the number.  That way all UPC and EAN schemes, including UPC-A, UPC-E, EAN-8, and EAN-13, match to a common routine.  The weights are then {3,1}, the divisor is 10, and PDA is false.  Extending the weights must be done by anchoring the rightmost weight digit to the rightmost inputData digit, so the weights of 31 become

```
         <-31
1313131313131
9780321146533
```

The same technique handles any repeating set of weights.  With the Luhn algorithm for credit cards using a 21 weight, the same routine works for 13 digit Visa cards, 15 digit AmEx cards, and 16 digit Visa cards.  But it then requires external validation of the length of the number of digits, so it doesn't save much.

Comment: The only three that concern me (at present, anyway) are the first three (UPCA, EAN13, and 128). Isn't it so, though, that the final/trailing "1" in UPCA and EAN13 is the check digit position? My calculations show both of those multipliers being "3" on the end for this reason. IOW, EAN13 is 1,3,1,3,1,3,1,3,1,3,1,3, checkDigit, IOW 12 barcode vals + a check digit val for a total of 13. Similarly with UPCA. I have successfully checked results for UPCA and EAN13 using this method. 128 is the bizarre one - thanks for that info, because without that my 128 algorithm would have been way wrong.

Comment: UPC-A is 12 digits, so when you start with 3 you end with 1.  EAN-13 is 13 digits, so when you start with 1, you end with 1.  But try to not think of it as "every other digit", think of it as a set of weights.

Comment: Oh, I think I get what you're saying.  This algorithm doesn't care which digit is designated as the check digit.  As long as the sum of all digits (divided by the modulus) is zero, it passes. But that means you need to include the check digit in the weights and length just as you would any other digit.

Comment: @ClayShannon, I fixed the Code128 check digit explanation above (sorry, I had it wrong.)  Just posting this in hopes you'll see it before you use the old code.

Answer (score 1):

Barcodes, although being of varying lengths and having different semantic meaning, still follow some basic rules in generating checksums. The code below can be copied into a small util for testing (or simply use the non-event-handling code):

To use this, create a WinForms app, and drop the following controls on it:

```
0) A button named button1; give it text something like "Calculate barcode and append it to label below", if desired
1) A button named button2; give it text something like "Valid barcode + czech digit", if desired
2) A label named label1, which displays the result of clicking button1
3) A textBox named textBox1, wherein you enter a raw barcode value (sans check digit) prior to clicking button1 OR enter a full barcode value (with check digit) prior to clicking button2

// "Calculate check sum" handler
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string barcodeWithoutCheckSum = textBox1.Text.Trim();
    string checkSum = GetBarcodeChecksum(barcodeWithoutCheckSum);
    string barcodeWithCheckSum = string.Format("{0}{1}", barcodeWithoutCheckSum, checkSum);
    label1.Text = barcodeWithCheckSum;
    textBox1.Focus();
}

// Verify/validate existing checksum handler
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string bcVal = textBox1.Text.Trim();
    bool validCheckDigit = isValidBarcodeWithCheckDigit(bcVal);
    MessageBox.Show(validCheckDigit ? string.Format("{0} is valid", bcVal) : string.Format("{0} invalid", bcVal));
}

public static string GetBarcodeChecksum(string barcode)
{
    int oddTotal;
    int oddTotalTripled;
    int evenTotal;
    // Which positions are odd or even depend on the length of the barcode, 
    // or more specifically, whether its length is odd or even, so:
    if (isStringOfEvenLen(barcode))
    {
        oddTotal = sumInsideOrdinals(barcode);
        oddTotalTripled = oddTotal * 3;
        evenTotal = sumOutsideOrdinals(barcode);
    }
    else
    {
        oddTotal = sumOutsideOrdinals(barcode);
        oddTotalTripled = oddTotal * 3;
        evenTotal = sumInsideOrdinals(barcode);
    }
    int finalTotal = oddTotalTripled + evenTotal;
    int modVal = finalTotal%10;
    int checkSum = 10 - modVal;
    if (checkSum == 10)
    {
        return "0";
    }
    return checkSum.ToString();
}

private static bool isStringOfEvenLen(string barcode)
{
    return (barcode.Length % 2 == 0);
}

// "EvenOrdinals" instead of "EvenVals" because values at index 0,2,4,etc. are seen by the 
// checkdigitmeisters as First, Third, Fifth, ... (etc.), not Zeroeth, Second, Fourth
private static int sumInsideOrdinals(string barcode)
{
    int cumulativeVal = 0;
    for (int i = barcode.Length-1; i > -1; i--)
    {
        if (i % 2 != 0)
        {
            cumulativeVal += Convert.ToInt16(barcode[i] - '0');
        }
    }
    return cumulativeVal;
}

// "OddOrdinals" instead of "OddVals" because values at index 1,3,5,etc. are seen by the 
// checkdigitmeisters as Second, Fourth, Sixth, ..., not First, Third, Fifth, ...
private static int sumOutsideOrdinals(string barcode)
{
    int cumulativeVal = 0;
    for (int i = barcode.Length - 1; i > -1; i--)
    {
        if (i % 2 == 0)
        {
            cumulativeVal += Convert.ToInt16(barcode[i] - '0');
        }
    }
    return cumulativeVal;
}

private static bool isValidBarcodeWithCheckDigit(string barcodeWithCheckDigit)
{
    string barcodeSansCheckDigit = barcodeWithCheckDigit.Substring(0, barcodeWithCheckDigit.Length - 1);
    string checkDigit = barcodeWithCheckDigit.Substring(barcodeWithCheckDigit.Length - 1, 1);
    //MessageBox.Show(string.Format("raw barcode portion is {0}", barcodeSansCheckDigit));
    //MessageBox.Show(string.Format("check portion is {0}", checkDigit));
    return GetBarcodeChecksum(barcodeSansCheckDigit) == checkDigit;
}
```

Comment: On second post, three different ways of calculating barcodes can be found here (the one above, the legacy one, and an "elegant" one from a poster over there: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/30829/is-one-of-these-approaches-better-or-are-they-just-different-radically-differe